# Unable to create set as value to a dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to create a set as a value to a dictionary.

```
fd = {}
fs = set()
fd['a'] = fs.add('x')
fd['a'] = fs.add('y')
```

The set is indeed created properly:

```
print(fs)
{'x','y'}
```

But the dictionary does not contain the set as the value.

```
print(fd)
{'a':None}
```

I thought any object can be a value in a dictionary. Why don't I get the set as the value for the given simple string key?

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: I expected output to be _{'a':{'x','y'}}_ . Instead I get _{'a':None}_
I believe I found the issue. Instead of using set.add() in the creation of the dictionary, if I first created the set and then added it as a value, it seems to work. So:
`fs = {'x','y'}
fd['a'] = s `
This seems to work.
But I still don't know why ` fd['a'] = fs.add('x') `does not work.

Comment: @MaheshKaria: `set`s are mutable.

Comment: Many "mutator" methods for Python objects (such as lists and sets) do NOT return a reference to the object.  This is an intentional implementation decision to discourage confusing between methods which mutate (modify) an object and those which return contents.  It all started with list.sort() vs. sorted(some_list).  Thus the expression fs.add(xxx) evaluates to None while modify the contents of fs.

Comment: `fs.add('x')` returns `None`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all add() is in-place operation and it returns nothing so when you are doing `fd['a'] = fs.add('x')` then  'x' gets added to list inside set and returns 'None' which gets assigned to dictionary 'fd' that the reason for dictionary key 'a' you're observing None. To solve this problem assign set object to dictionary key like `fd['a'] = fs`. I hope this helps (:

**code:**

```
fd = {}
fs = set()
fs.add('x')
fs.add('y')
fd['a'] = fs
print fd
```

**output:**

```
{'a': set(['y', 'x'])}
```

Comment: `set` is not immutable

Comment: sets are mutable.  The are NOT immutable.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a bit of a convention within Python that methods that change their object in-place tend to return `None`. Examples are `dict.update`, `list.append`, `list.extend`, `list.sort` (as opposed to `sorted(list)`) and as you experienced `set.add`.

Comment: Exactly!  This is what I've said in my comment.

Comment: @JimDennis I can see it is almost identical up to the sort vs. sorted thing ;-)

Answer (score 0):

When you add a value to the set via set.add() method, The return value of the function is None which gets assigned to the dictionary.

Instead first add the values to the set and then assign the value of set to the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
fd = {'a':set()}
fd['a'].add('x')
fd['a'].add('y')
print(fd)
```

May this help.